# Android Studio 0.5.0 - No auto code completion and error syntax recognizer after upgrading

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I upgraded Android Studio to 0.5.0 without any issues until I started writing code. It's so weird. Auto code completion didn't work any more. No drop-down list got showed up. Even worse, I intentionally wrote wrong syntax but the IDE failed to warn automatically as it still does at the scrolling line (on the right).

I'm sure that I've already changed into `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'`.

Any help?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out. The cause is, I accidentally turned **File > Power Save Mode** which does block auto completion, not because of Android Studio 0.5.0 itself.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings when you click the Sync Project With Gradle Files button? Does cleaning and rebuilding the project help? Anyhthing in the Gradle Console? Or Messages? or Event Log?

Comment: Syncing, cleaning and rebuilding is fine. Something wrong with syntax highlighting and code completion. The AndroidDevTool team just rolled out 0.5.1. I've upgraded already and the problem still got unsolved.

Comment: Thanks. Got solved. See my update.

Comment: Wow! I've forgotten about that too! Thanks so much!~

Comment: @ThuyTrinh Thanks for the question, did the same mistake.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, that's because I accidentally turned on *File* > *Power Save Mode*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing. In my case I think it's because of custom sourceSets in build.gradle. For me, commenting out the 'resources.srcDirs' line and re-syncing Gradle made my syntax highlighting come back.

This idea came from

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66794&q=android%20studio&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Surely it much be a bug, but at least this is a work-around.

Comment: Thanks for good reminder on ``sourceSets``. However, after commenting out, I still didn't manage.

Comment: Duplicate bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66758 has the same advice. What's in your sourceSets stanza?

Comment: They've rolled out 0.5.1 but it still doesn't fix this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered, after having this problem more than once, that if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, you get a popup to change the highlighting level.  In my case, the "Import Popup" item was checked.  Unchecking this box restored the editor to show errors.  This popup also has an item for "Power Save Mode".