# Error Detecting in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio, I have one question, in Android Studio, when I have a syntax error or something like that, Android Studio doesn't display any indicator at the beginning of the line like Eclipse does at all, it only show a wavy red line in the breadcrumb trail and it highlights the error in red also, but that is kinda hard to detect, is there anyway I can enable that feature like in Eclipse. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio (IntellJ) displays the errors (and other file information, such as changes) on the right hand side of the editor window in the `Validation side bar`. This area represents the entire file and different colored marks are displayed in this area to show where in the file these items are. You can also click inside this area to just directly to that area, or you can just hover over it with the pointer and a popup will display the code at that area.

For more information, see the [IntellJ documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/familiarize-yourself-with-intellij-idea-editor.html)

Below is the relevant info from the site:

[image: IntellJ Editor]

> **5. Validation side bar / marker bar**
>
> This is the bar to the right from the editing area, showing the
>   green, red or yellow box on its top depending on whether your code is
>   okay, or contains errors or warnings. This bar also displays active
>   red, yellow, white, green and blue navigation stripes that let you
>   jump exactly to the erroneous code, changed lines, search results, or
>   TODO items.

Comment: Hey, thank you man. that helps alot, but would be better if android studio could show like eclipse does.

Comment: No problem. I actually prefer the way Android Studio does it.

Answer (score 1):

Turned off 
"File > Power Save Mode".

I was refered by ... 
[Android Studio 0.5.0 - No auto code completion and error syntax recognizer after upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255646/android-studio-0-5-0-no-auto-code-completion-and-error-syntax-recognizer-after)