# why android studio do not recognize java file

Tags: android, android-studio

i loaded a android sample project but it shows java file as normal file in IDE.

Build: 1.0.1, AI-135.1641136, 20141211, 1.8.0_25-b18x64-Oracle-Corporation,-Windows-8(amd64)-v6.2--(1920x1080)

[image]

Comment: Thats odd ! did you try closing and reopening IDE?

Comment: yes, i have restarted IDE but it still exist. anyways code compile compiles and runs. i have tried removing and adding file name in gradle workespace file too.

Comment: How about if you click the Sync with Gradle Files button in the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
The solution is to deactivate Power Save Mode

> File > Power Save Mode

References: [Android Studio 0.5.0 - No auto code completion and error syntax recognizer after upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255646/android-studio-0-5-0-no-auto-code-completion-and-error-syntax-recognizer-after)

Comment: I have no idea why you were downvoted. I just did this now and Android Studio has now sprung back into life.

Answer (score 0):

When you create file with .java extension. Try to create class

File--> new ---> JAVA Class

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen in the **Android** view when you have a java file with multiple root-level classes in it.  In this instance, Studio shows the filename rather than the class name in the tree explorer.  For example a file called JSON.java with the following contents will show up in the tree explorer as **JSON.java** with the classes as children:

```
public class JSON
{
    ...
}

class DateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    ...
}
```

[image: Tree explorer]

Since you can't expand your java file in the image you provided I imagine this is not causing your specific issue but it could be related.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try This Build-> Rebuild Project

Try this way also Build->Clean Project[image]